# Measure-preserving map of sphere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading Stein and Shakarchi's Real Analysis, trying to do some exercises and puzzled about ex4 of Chapter 6.
Let $r$ be a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^d$. As I know it's proved that the mapping $\pi : x \mapsto r(x)$ preserves Lebesgue measure. The problem is to show that it induces a measure-preserving map of the sphere $S^{d-1}$.
I tried to prove it like this: It can be shown that $S^{d-1} \subseteq ker(r)$ and there is a natural projection $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^d-\{0\} \rightarrow S^{d-1}\, ,\, x \mapsto \frac{x}{|x|}$. How can I show that the mapping $\varphi \circ\pi$ preserves measure? From this problem, $d\mu(r(x))=d\mu(x)$.  Is this true because $d\mu (r(\frac{x}{|x|})) = d\mu(\frac{1}{|x|} x)$? Is is sufficient to prove this problem?

Comment: You have misinterpreted the question. The mapping $\phi \circ \pi$ is not measure preserving. To see that, take any measurable set $X \subset \mathbb R^d$ with Lebesgue measure $m(X) \in (0, +\infty)$, and any $a \in \mathbb R_{>0} \setminus \{1\}$. Then $\pi(aX) = \pi(X)$ and hence $\phi\circ\pi(aX)$ and $\phi\circ\pi(X)$ have the same measure, whereas $aX$ and $X$ don't (since $m(aX) = am(X) \neq m(X)$).

What the problem asks is to show that the restriction of $\pi$ to $S^{d-1}$ defines a measure preserving map from $S^{d-1}$ to $S^{d-1}$.

Comment: Some other comments regarding your post: (a) $S^{d-1} \not \subseteq \ker(r)$ since $\ker(r) = \{0\}$. (b) There is no reason to introduce the symbol "$\pi$" for the mapping $x \mapsto r(x)$; "$r$" works perfectly fine. :) (c) This is Exercise 4 of Chapter 6 at the edition of the book that I have (1st). The book has 7 chapters in total. Has another chapter been added since then?

Comment: @posilon Thanks for your reply. This is from Chapter 6 and I edited that. But I still cannot figure it out why $\pi (aX) = \pi(X)$. $\pi$ is a rotation on a measurable set.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Replace $\pi(aX)=\pi(X)$ with $\phi \circ \pi(aX) = \phi \circ \pi(X)$ in my comment and then hopefully it will make more sense!

Comment: In addition, $X$ should not contain $0$ in order for everything to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

What a coincidence! I just have finished this exercise today!

You need to refer to section 5 in Chapter 6 to find the definition of "measure-preserving transformation". In this exercise, our measure space is $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)=(S^{d-1},\mathcal M,\sigma)$. Given any set $E\subset S^{d-1}$ we let $\widetilde{E}=\{x\in\mathbb R^d: x/|x|\in E,0<|x|<1\}$. We shall say $E\in\mathcal M$ exactly when $\widetilde{E}$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^d$, and define $\sigma(E)=d\cdot m(\widetilde{E})$.

Let $E\in\mathcal M$, then by definition, $\sigma(E)=d\cdot m(\widetilde{E})$ and $\sigma(rE)=d\cdot m(\widetilde{rE})$. But $r\widetilde{E}=\widetilde{rE}$ since
\begin{align*}
x\in \widetilde{rE}&\iff x=\rho\theta\ \ \text{for some }\rho\leq1,\theta\in rE\\&\iff x=\rho r(\alpha)  \ \text{for some }\alpha\in E\\&\iff x=r(\rho\alpha)\\&\iff x\in r\widetilde{E}.
\end{align*}
Thus $\sigma(rE)=d\cdot m(r\widetilde{E})=d\cdot m(\widetilde{E})=\sigma(E)$, so $r$ preserves measures on $S^{d-1}$.